# Cryptsetup not accepting the VALID password

Tags: password, luks, cryptsetup, devuan

I'm at my wit's end here. I recently updated my distro. Something like 300+ packages were updated so trying to downgrade one by one would be a nightmare and so I'm trying to get this to work but my computer simply refuses to cooperate with me.

I know for a fact the password I am entering is valid because I have an old version of the same operating system that I keep around for recovery purposes. There, it accepts the password no problem. However on my updated version it simply refuses. It doesn't matter what keymap I am using, what encoding I have set on my terminal, what terminal I use, if I use a backup header, what backup header I use (I have several). I am completely baffled! I even downgraded to what was (presumably) the old version of cryptsetup I was using before.

All it says is "No key available with this passphrase." Nothing more or less. Again, I know for a *fact* that's not correct because on my recovery OS it loads without issue.

Comment: luksDump? some years ago there was an issue with whirlpool that caused passphrases to stop being accepted, but it's strange to still run into this issue today...

Comment: Can you access your current system from your backup, or from a live distro? To see if the problem is with the storage or the software.

Comment: Please run the `luksOpen` command with `--debug` to get more information. Also check journal for any kernel/device mapper errors.

Comment: If that's at boot, are you really sure the keymap is changed correctly (I know you wrote about the keymap, but no details were given)? Can you type this visibly during boot (usually after like 10 failures you might be  given a shell from within initramfs to test this.)